# Returning index of true value

Tags: python, loops, numpy

for the code written below, I want to print the index of values in `samples_avg` which return true in `maxlist` for each list in `samples_avg`. So for the list

```
samples_avg = [[1, 12, 3], [15000, 4, 3], [1, 144, 45]]
```

I would expect a return value like

```
filtered = [[], [0], [1, 2]]
```

because there is no index for which the condition is true in the first list, it is true at index 0 for the second list, and is true at indexes 1 and 2 in the last list within `samples_avg`

```
samples_avg = [[1, 12, 3], [15000, 4, 3], [1, 144, 45]]
def check(samples_avg):
    filtered = []
    maxval = [max(x) for x in zip(*samples_avg)]
    maxlist = ([r >= (m/5) for row in samples_avg for r, m in zip(row, maxval)])

    results =[[] for i in samples_avg]
    for i in results:
        filtered.append([x for x, y in zip(samples_avg[i], maxlist) if y == True])
        print (np.where((filtered) is True))
```

This currently returns three empty arrays. How can I fix this so the arrays contain the indexes? any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am actually confused by the `m/5` thing but nvm. Use `enumerate` like the answer from @Adam.Er8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just modified your list comprehension a little, using enumerate to get the actual index, and using the condition is true in an if clause instead of a the map value.

try this:

```py
samples_avg = [[1, 12, 3], [15000, 4, 3], [1, 144, 45]]
def check(samples_avg):
    maxval = [max(x) for x in zip(*samples_avg)]
    return [[i for i,(r, m) in enumerate(zip(row, maxval)) if r >= (m/5)] for row in samples_avg]

print(check(samples_avg))
```

Output:

```
[[], [0], [1, 2]]
```